# How can I test WebSockets (using Pusher) with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, rspec, push, websocket

I am looking for successful methods for testing WebSocket push events using RSpec. My application currently uses Pusher App, but more broad information relating to WebSockets is most welcome.

Ideally, I'd like something as simple as:

```
  parsed_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  parsed_body["error"].should == "xyzError"
```

...which I have found to be an awesomely convenient way to test for JSON responses.

Sincere thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Tristan Dunn came out with this awesome gem: https://github.com/tristandunn/pusher-fake

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket server is remote service. It's good way to stub any requests to remote services and mock responses from these ones.

Comment: Could you give an example of how one would stub the requests?